# Angular sorting drag'n drop list cdkDropListDropped: Why does my items' order property is updated before I do it?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an array of JSON objects containing an `order` property; I have too an Angular Drag'nDrop list to sort these objects, whose model is this array. When I reorder it, it should update the value of `order` of all the items. This is done by the following code I've written:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { StateService } from '../services/state.service';
import {CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-states',
  templateUrl: './states.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./states.component.scss']
})
export class StatesComponent {

    states: any[] = [
        { id: 0, order: 0, nom: 'test0' },
        { id: 1, order: 1, nom: 'test1' },
    ];

    
    constructor(private statesService: StateService) { }
    
    drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
        moveItemInArray(this.states, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
        console.log(this.states);
        this.states.forEach(_ => {
            _.order = this.states.indexOf(_);
        });
    }

}
```

And the HTML code:

```
<nb-card>
    <nb-card-body>
        <div cdkDropList class="states_list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
            <div class="state_element" cdkDrag *ngFor="let state of states">{{ state.nom }}</div>
        </div>
    </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

## The problem

After having reordered one item, the function `drop` is called; the latter calls `moveItemInArray` which moves the elements of the array `states` accordingly to the user's drag'n drop. Then I display the contents of this array: the problem is that at this moment, the `order` property's value of the elements has already changed! However, `moveItemInArray` doesn't work on any element's property (it just moves the elements of the model). The only part of the code that can update `order` is within the `forEach`... which is located after the `console.log`.

**So why does the `console.log` shows the data's state which takes into account the code within the `forEach`, knowing that `console.log` is located before?**

### Expected behavior

1. You drag "test1" before "test0".
2. It should display: "{id: 1, order: 1, nom: 'test1'} - {id: 0, order: 0, nom: 'test0'}"

### Actual behavior

1. You drag "test1" before "test0".
2. It actually display: "{id: 1, order: 0, nom: 'test1'} - {id: 0, order: 1, nom: 'test0'}"

## Minimal and Testable Executable Code

- In an AngularJS empty project, you can simply copy/paste the above code and test it by drag'n dropping the elements and inspecting the console's display.

## Hints

- No asynchronous behavior is known to be involved here.
- `moveItemInArray` only shifts the lements in the model array; in particular, it doesn't change the value of any property of the elements of the model, including such a property `order`

Answer (score 0):

Are you states being altered from another location, such as within your `StateService` or within the `NbCardComponent`?

When you strip those, it is working as you expected, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xmsna7?file=src/app/states.component.ts